# My iPhone 4s will not make or accept calls

Tags: iphone

I have done a factory reset on my iPhone 4s and it will no longer make calls or receive them. It goes straight to voicemail when called, and when I dial out it just beeps twice and disconnects.

Comment: After you factory reset your phone, did it activate on your carrier?  Sounds like your phone is not activated.

Answer (score 1):

This would have nothing to do with the phones settings, have you tried calling your contract provider? If that doesn't fix the problem i recommend taking it to the apple store where they can do a diagnoses of the problem.